# Is there any way to specify "any character but [aeiou]" in a PHP regular expression?

Tags: php, regex, regex-negation

I am developing a C# Web Service whose responses are always collections of things. Since I am too lazy and do not want to explicitly define collections of things, I implemented a generic class representing a collection of things that can be serialized using XML.

Now, ASP.NET usually gives horrible names to generics, such as `CollectionOfOrdenPago` (in Spanish, "orden de pago" means "payment order") or `PageOfLineaDetalleReporte` (in Spanish, "línea de detalle de reporte" means "report detail line"). I wanted to give my collections more sensible names like `OrdenesPago` ("payment orders") or `LineasDetalleReporte` ("report detail lines"), so I defined the following method:

```
internal static string Pluralize(string input)
{
    int i = 0;
    while (++i < input.Length)
        if (!char.IsLower(input[i]))
            break;

    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(input);
    if ("aeiou".IndexOf(input[i - 1]) == -1)
        builder.Insert(i++, 'e');
    builder.Insert(i, 's');

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

---

This Web Service is consumed by a PHP website, which I am developing as well. Since pluralizing a noun does not seem to be a good reason to call the C# Web Service, I reimplemented the `Pluralize` function in PHP:

```
function pluralize($element) {
    return preg_replace_callback('/^([A-Z][a-z]*)([A-Z]|$)/', function($args) {
        // If the first word ends in consonant, append "e" first. After that, append "s".
        return preg_replace('/([B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z])$/i', '\1e', $args[1]) . "s{$args[2]}";
    }, $element);
}
```

But I am still not happy. The term `[B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z]` is *ugly*. As in the C# method, I would like to specify "a character not in [aeiou]" as a term. Is that possible?

Comment: @tchrist: Sí, lo revisé. Muchas gracias. Lo implementaré cuando tenga que procesar texto escrito en algún lenguaje humano. (Aunque, para ser honesto, no me gustaría tener que procesar lenguajes humanos en PHP.) :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use a negated character class

```
[^AEIOU]
```

instead of `[B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z]`.

**N.B.** as per [@fireeyedboy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/165154/fireeyedboy)'s comment, this regex matches non-alphabetic characters as well.

Comment: I initially up-voted this, but this would match none alphabetic characters as well. I think he needs any alphabetic character except  the vowels. If you would update your answer to reflect that scenario, you'd have my up-vote as I don't have a clever answer for this myself to tell you the truth. :)

Comment: @fire: good point, thank you - I think that's actually not a problem in this case due to the regex used in `preg_replace_callback`.

Comment: @Matt Ball: Ah, you are right, of course. I hadn't noticed that! +1 it is then. :)

Comment: @tchrist: because of accents, or the larger pluralization algorithm used? I only tried to answer the question that the OP was asking, which was about de-uglifying the `[B-DF-HJ-NP-TV-Z]` expression.

Comment: @Matt Ball: I think @tchrist thought I was trying to work with actual Spanish text. @tchrist: As @Matt Ball said, I was just trying to de-uglify the expression selecting consonants.

Answer (score 4):

Sure. A caret (`^`) negates a character class:

```
/[^aeiou]/i
```

Comment: As written, that will also match punctuation, whitespace, and important letters like *á, é, í, ó, ú,* and *ü*, all of which occur in Spanish.

Comment: @tchrist: Correct. Well, he did ask for "any character but [aeiou]" :) On a serious note, as pointed out by Matt Ball, the `preg_replace_callback` already narrows down the candidate character set.

Answer (score 2):

First, your string needs to be in Normalization Form D.  Otherwise you will miss things like *María*, *Ángeles*, *Argüelles*,  and *Bogotá*.  Here’s an example in Perl:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use utf8;
use strict;
use warnings;    
use Unicode::Normalize qw(NFD NFC);    
binmode(STDOUT, ":utf8") || die;    
my @names = qw(María Ángeles Argüelles Bogotá cáñamo);
for my $orig ("@names", @names) {
    my $nfd = NFD($orig);
    $nfd =~ s/( (?: (?! [aeiou] ) (?= \pL ) \X ) +)/<$1>/xig;
    print NFC($nfd), "\n";
}
```

When run, that prints out this:

```
<M>a<r>ía Á<ng>e<l>e<s> A<rg>üe<ll>e<s> <B>o<g>o<t>á <c>á<ñ>a<m>o
<M>a<r>ía
Á<ng>e<l>e<s>
A<rg>üe<ll>e<s>
<B>o<g>o<t>á
<c>á<ñ>a<m>o
```

I don’t how to pull in the needed NFD function in PHP, but the  rest should be completely transferable once you figure that part out.

Comment: Don't worry about special characters (á, é, í, ó, ú, ñ). I am working with class names, which cannot contain special characters in most programming languages.

Comment: @Eduardo: They can in Perl and Java and Go language; is it true they really can’t in most programming languages? Which ones are anti-international? :(

Comment: My class names must match the names of the tables whose rows I am retrieving. (That is the way I designed my own mini-framework.) And the table names don't have tildes. (In my own defense: I did neither implement the database, nor choose the names of the tables!)